# Boolean Algebra, stuck

Tags: calculus, analysis, logic

I'm having trouble simplifying this Boolean Algebra equation. Can anyone help?

XY'Z + X'Y'Z + XYZ + XY'Z

Comment: Have you tried a Venn diagram for three sets? An answer comes out very quickly that way. Note that the first and last terms in your expression are identical: removing one of them is a quick simplification, though simpler expressions are possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=> Y'Z(X+X')+XZ(Y+Y') //BY DISTRIBUTIVE AND ASSOCIATIVE PROPERTY 
=> Y'Z+XZ             //X+X'=1 AND Y+Y'=1  USING BOOLEAN TABLE PROOF 
=> Z(Y'+X)            //BY DISTRIBUTIVE PROPERTY

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick response! Appreciate the help! Can't believe it was that easy.